# How to remove indent from list in table?

Tags: tables, lists, indentation, itemize

I've table with list as mentioned below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
 \textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} \\
\hline
Definition&\noindent{\begin{itemize} \item Critical break-fix. \item Production down with no workaround. \item Multiple users impacted. \item Unavailability of Systems. \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize} \item Urgent break-fix. \item Production issue with workaround. \item Multiple users impacted. \item Multiple records impacted. \item Unavailability of system interfaces. \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize} \item Small Maintenance Issues. \item Non critical Bug Fix with workaround. \item No immediate impact. \item Single user/record impacted.  \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize} \item Small Maintenance Issues. \item Not a break-fix. \item A nice to have feature. \item 1- 7 person days of effort. \end{itemize}}\\
\hline
Response Time &3 Business Hours&5 Business Hours&1 Business Day&4 Business Days\\
\hline
Resolution Time &1 Business Day&2 Business Days&5 Business Days&As per mutual agreement\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

It's giving output as [image: table below]

How can I remove extra space before list items?

Comment: Try something like `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]` and adapt the distance to your need. You also need the enumitem package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `leftmargin` option from the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4}\\
\hline
Definition&\noindent{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] \item Critical break-fix. \item Production down with no workaround. \item Multiple users impacted. \item Unavailability of Systems. \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] \item Urgent break-fix. \item Production issue with workaround. \item Multiple users impacted. \item Multiple records impacted. \item Unavailability of system interfaces. \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] \item Small Maintenance Issues. \item Non critical Bug Fix with workaround. \item No immediate impact. \item Single user/record impacted.  \end{itemize}}&\noindent{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] \item Small Maintenance Issues. \item Not a break-fix. \item A nice to have feature. \item 1- 7 person days of effort. \end{itemize}}\\
\hline
Response Time &3 Business Hours&5 Business Hours&1 Business Day&4 Business Days\\
\hline
Resolution Time &1 Business Day&2 Business Days&5 Business Days&As per mutual agreement\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output]

**EDIT** Here are some improvements to get a *better* output (using Daleif suggestions)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Attribute}&\textbf{P1}&\textbf{P2}&\textbf{P3}&\textbf{P4}\\
\hline
Definition&\RaggedRight
\noindent{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] 
\item Critical break-fix. 
\item Production down with no workaround. 
\item Multiple users impacted. 
\item Unavailability of Systems. 
\end{itemize}}&\RaggedRight
\noindent{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] 
\item Urgent break-fix. 
\item Production issue with workaround. 
\item Multiple users impacted. 
\item Multiple records impacted. 
\item Unavailability of system interfaces. 
\end{itemize}}&\RaggedRight
\noindent{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] 
\item Small Maintenance Issues. 
\item Non critical Bug Fix with workaround. 
\item No immediate impact. 
\item Single user/record impacted. 
\end{itemize}}&\RaggedRight
\noindent{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm] 
\item Small Maintenance Issues. 
\item Not a break-fix. 
\item A nice to have feature. 
\item 1- 7 person days of effort. 
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
Response Time &3 Business Hours&5 Business Hours&1 Business Day&4 Business Days\\
\hline
Resolution Time &1 Business Day&2 Business Days&5 Business Days&As per mutual agreement\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image: Output2]

Comment: The math mode switches aren't needed in the header row.

Comment: Might be useful to add `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package to those columns such that the text isn't so stretched.

Comment: @daleif Sure, it could be nice to fix the stretch of the columns but it wasn't exactly the question of the OP.